# Vim shortcuts won't work in tmux

Tags: shortcut-keys, vim, tmux, vimrc

I'm starting with tmux and i'm with some difficulties. I searched and didn't find anything that helped.

When I open VIM in a tmux's session, the shift + hjkl doesn't work. I searched for a solution and found one that said to me to remap the command. So, i remaped with ctrl.

```
map OC <Right>
map OD <Left>
map [C <S-Right>
map [D <S-Left>
map OB <Down>
map [B <S-Down>
map OA <Up>
map [A <S-Up>
```

But now I found a thing rather annoying. When I use ctrl + arrows, vim changes back to visual mode, that makes me to have to change back to insert mode. Are there another solution for this problem?

Comment: This might sounds kinda noob but, what does `shift + hjkl` does?

Cause if it's navigating at farther paces why not using the equivalents? like `Ctrl + D / Ctrl + U / $ and ^`?

Still though, i don't know what `shift + hjkl` does, please explain. `tmux -V` will help to clarify more too.